# Send all values from a combobox to an array variable through post method

Tags: php, arrays, post

I want to be able to send all values from a combobox inside a form, into a php $_POST variable.

**NOTICE:** I do not need to send the selected values but everything contaning multiple select.

My attemp was this (it's not the right way but I think it's close):

**HTML code:**

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form" id="list2">
  <select multiple size="8" style="width:280">
    <option value="aline.chastel" name="user[]">Aline Chastel</option>
    <option value="bruno.freitas" name="user[]">Bruno Sousa Freitas</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

**PHP code:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  echo $_POST['user'][0].' '.$_POST['user'][1];
}
```

Expected outcome: aline.chastel bruno.freitas

**My workaround:**

After research I found out it wasn't possible to do this with pure HTML, so I had to use javascript and AJAX. I took all children elements and joined them in one string with '|'s:

```
     $("#btngrafico").click(function() {
        for(i=0;i<$("#list2").children().length;i++){
            var co_usuario = $("#list2").children('option').eq(i).attr('value');
            var usuario = $("#list2").children('option').eq(i).text();
            if (i==0){
                arr_co_usuario = co_usuario;
            }else{
                arr_co_usuario = arr_co_usuario + '|' + co_usuario;
            }
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'GraficoBarras.php',
            type:'POST',
            data: { 'arr_co_usuario': arr_co_usuario,'Month1':Month1,'Year1':Year1,'Month2':Month2,'Year2':Year2},
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#loader").show();
            },
            success: function(output_string){ 
                $("#ListadoRelatorio").append(output_string);
            }
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

your `name` attribute should be in [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) tag, like:

```
<select multiple size="8" style="width:280" name="user[]">
    <option value="aline.chastel">Aline Chastel</option>
    <option value="bruno.freitas">Bruno Sousa Freitas</option>
</select>
```

to see the data on PHP side on form submission, do:

```
print_r($_POST["user"]);
if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['user'] as $name) {
        echo $name."<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sudhir but still shows as ´Undefined index: user´

Comment: @HerlandCid it should show Array ( [0] => aline.chastel [1] => bruno.freitas ) for print_r($_POST["user"])

Comment: buddy @Sudhir, ive tried all forms of your code but the expected outcome is not working.

Comment: thanks @TBI once I did multiple selection it worked, but is there a way to send all data regardless of selection?

Comment: alright, so you want to get data in post without any selection from multiselect ?

Comment: @HerlandCid without any selection from multiselect there wont be any data in $_POST..

Answer (score 1):

you must use multi-select list , for this purpose , because select list only send one value which is selected.

if you only want to use this select list then i think you only can get all the options via jquery

Comment: yes I know @ShahRukh that's why I find it hard to send all these values from a select type. And I already have it as select multiple.